# On clicking a link, url changes but not redirected to the required page in laravel 5.2 blade

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5, href

I have a list page where there are images. On clicking each image, the page should go to its corresponding detail page. So I have an a href attribut where I defined route by passing its id.

**Below is my blade**

```
@foreach (array_chunk($program, 3, true) as $prgms)
  <div class="card-deck mb-30">
     @foreach ($prgms as $prgm)
       <div class="col-md-4 card">
        <a href="{{url('programDtls/'.$prgm['id'])}}">
         <img class="card-img-top" src="{{asset(App\Http\Controllers\Controller::getThumbPath($prgm['thumbnail'],$folder='home'))}}"  alt="Card image cap">
         <div class="card-body">
         <h4 class="card-title">{{$prgm['title']}}</h4>
          <p class="card-text clsComInnerText mb-10">{{$prgm['description']}}</p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{date('d-m-Y',strtotime($prgm['episode_date']))}} {{$prg_time}} {{$day = date('l', strtotime($prgm['episode_date']))}} </small></p>
          </div>
          </a>
          </div>
      @endforeach
   </div>
@endforeach
```

**List page Route**

```
Route::get('programListPage/{id}', 'ProgramListPageController@index');
```

**Detail page Route**

```
Route::get('programDtls/{id}', 'ProgramDtlsController@index');
```

**ProgramListPageController@index**

```
public function index($id) {

    $category_details = Category::select('title','description')->where('id',$id)->first();

    $program = ProgramDetails::select('id','title','description','thumbnail','programs_id','episode_date')->where('category_id',$id)->where('category_videos',1)->where('enabled',1)->get()->toArray();

    $trending_video = ProgramDetails::select('video_url','thumbnail')->where('is_trending',1)->where('category_id',$id)->first();

    if(count($trending_video)>0){
        $trending = $trending_video['video_url'];
        $image = $trending_video['thumbnail'];

    }else{
        $trending = " ";
        $image = " ";
    }

    if(count($program)>0){
        foreach ($program as $prgm) {




            $prg_times = Programslots::where('programs_id',$prgm['programs_id'])->get();
                foreach($prg_times as $time){

            $prg_time = date('h:ia ', strtotime($time['show_time']));
            }
        }
    }else{
            $prg_time = " ";
            $day = " ";
    }

    return View('programListPage', ['category_details' => $category_details, 'program' => $program,'prg_time' => $prg_time,'trending_video'=>$trending,'image'=>$image]);
}
```

**ProgramDtlsController@index**

```
public function index($program_details_id) {



$program_id = ProgramDetails::select('programs_id','description','title','episode_no','video_url','thumbnail')->where('id',$program_details_id)->get();

    $program = Programs::select('id','poster_image','video_url','is_video','description')->where('id',$program_id[0]['programs_id'])->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
   $video_url=ProgramDetails::select('id','video_url','thumbnail','title','episode_no','description','promo_url')->where('enabled', 1)->where('programs_id',$program[0]['id'])->get()->toArray();
   $featured_image= Programs::select('poster_image')->where('is_featured', 1)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();

     $image_album= AlbumMaster::select('id','album_title','cover_image')->where('enabled', 1)->where('program_details_id',$program_details_id)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();

     $image_gallery=PhotoGallery::select()->where('album_master_id',$image_album[0]['id'])->get();


    $result = array('program_id'=>$program_id,'program' => $program,'video_url'=>$video_url,'featured_image'=>$featured_image,'image'=>$image_gallery,'image_album'=>$image_album);
     return View('programDtls')->with($result);
  }
```

Here what happens is, when I click an image the url changes like the below

```
http://localhost/abcde/public/programDtls/31
```

But displays the same list page itself. But if I again refreshes with the details page url, it moves to the corresponding detail page.What I need is to go to the detail page on clicking the images in the listing page. Thanks in advance,

Comment: add your list page route and controller code

Comment: i have edited the question, by adding controller and list page route. Please have a look at this. Thank you

Comment: try `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: route and cache cleared. But not working

Comment: Show us also the second controller index() function

Comment: I edited the question by adding the second controller index() function.Please have a look at this. Thank you